# Remove white space after chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

First, I have this code :

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

    \newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \makeatletter\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@\addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{0em}\setlength\@tempdima{1.4em}\begingroup\parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth\parfillskip -\@pnumwidth\leavevmode \bfseries \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\hskip -\leftskip#1\nobreak\ \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfil\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par\endgroup\fi}\makeatother

    \makeatletter
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents..
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla

    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
    contents...
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    contents...\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\end{document}
```

The result of this code is

[image]

Now, I want to add word "CHAPTER" before number of chapter, the code become

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \titlecontents{chapter}[6em]{\bigskip\bfseries}%\vspace{1cm}%
    {\contentslabel[ \chaptername~\thecontentslabel]{5.5em}}%
    {}%numberless chapters%
    {\hfill\contentspage}[\medskip]%

    \newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \makeatletter\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@\addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{0em}\setlength\@tempdima{1.4em}\begingroup\parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth\parfillskip -\@pnumwidth\leavevmode \bfseries \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\hskip -\leftskip#1\nobreak\ \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfil\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par\endgroup\fi}\makeatother

    \makeatletter

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents..
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla

    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
    contents...
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    contents...\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\end{document}
```

The result of this code is

[image]

I don't want after "Chapter" appears blank space, like first image. 
I want the "Contents" and "Bibliography" in the left side.
I want the dots appear.
Like this picture :
[image]
Become this :
[image]

How to do that?

Comment: The information that the table of contents is on page 13 is obviously redundant, as one is reading exactly that page, but I know that institution requirements are often beyond human understanding.

Comment: Sorry, this is just example, the page 13 should be 1

Comment: Whatever page the TOC appears in, the listed number will be the same, wouldn't it? So it's redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `tocbasic` instead `tocloft`. (Warning: Do not load both packages `tocbasic` and `tocloft`!)

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}% load as last package

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
contents...
\section{Latar Belakang}
contents...
\subsection{ABCD}
contents
\subsection{EFGH}
...
\section{Rumusan Masalah}
\vspace{0.3cm}
blablabla
\section{Tujuan Penulisan}
\vspace{0.25cm}
blablabla..

\chapter{DASAR TEORI}
contents...
\chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
contents...
\chapter{PENUTUP}
contents...
\chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
contents
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

---

For chapter entries with bold dots use:

```
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! @esdd ! but I want the dots is bold.. How to make bold dots?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `titletoc` here is a solution with this package:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm, outer=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

    \titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
    [0pt]% <left>
    {\vspace{1ex}\bfseries}% <above-code>
    {\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel\quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
    {}% <numberless-entry-format>
    {\titlerule*[0.696pc]{\scriptsize.} \contentspage}% <filler-page-format>
     [\vspace{2pt}]


    \newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@\addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{0em}\setlength\@tempdima{1.4em}\begingroup\parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth\parfillskip -\@pnumwidth\leavevmode
         \bfseries \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\hskip -\leftskip#1\nobreak\
         \leaders \hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}
         \hfil\nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par\endgroup\fi}
     \makeatother

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents..
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla

    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
    contents...
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    contents...\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}

\end{document}
```

[image]